# How to (re)generate and find dhl tracking number

Tags: algorithm, dhl

Does anyone know the algorithm to (re)generate DHL tracking number?

Like that one to calculate a Barcode from most shops, fortunately because they are standardized by the EU (if I don't mix up things).
Maybe this algorithm is privacy-protected by DHL and has a complicated calculating with customer keys.

Can someone help me there?

Comment: A DHL tracking number usually is a kind of consecutive number on the packet stamp, which can be bought and stored and is scanned during packet acceptance. Even if there are online marks/stamps, which are generated, the tracking number itself just points to the stamp number. This is what I've learned during a short assignment at a DHL partner, not sure if it's technically precise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we should not be expected to have any knowledge of the internal workings of DHL.

Comment: Thank you.
So in my understanding a tracking number is a result of DHLs internal processes including consecutive calculation.
No chance to get the algorithm :( If that helps anyway...